# Set caption centered below TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to have the following two graphs with the captions *below* the chart, with each caption nicely in the middle below the chart. I have run the following, but the captions just end up in different places. Any tips?

I have put placeholder captions that are quite long, as my captions need to be more than 1-2 lines.

```
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.913]
    \clip (-1,-0.5) rectangle (1.785,1.785);
    {
    \draw[red] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{max(0.7*(3*log10(\x+0.23)+4*(abs(\x-0.35))^0.1-2.6+0.67*(abs(\x-0.35))^1.63/12),0)});
    \draw[blue] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{1.24*(\x^2.576)/(0.2+\x^2.24)});
    \draw[green] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{1.24*(\x^(1.15*1.4))/(0.21+\x^1.4)});
    \draw[black] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{1.24*(\x^(1.22*0.5))/(0.21+\x^0.5)});
    }
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.785,1.785);
    \draw [dotted] (1,0) node[below]{$1$} -- (1,3);
    \draw [dotted] (0,1.1161) node[left]{$1$} -- (3,1.1161);
    \node at (1.6065,-0.08925) {$v_1$};
    \node at (-.4,3.85) {\footnotesize $\frac{x_{p}}{x_{s}}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
    \captionof{figure}{caption 1 caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1
    }
    \vfill
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \end{minipage}\qquad
    \begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
     \clip (-0.7,-0.5) rectangle (4,4);
    {
    \draw[red] plot[domain=0.398:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{max(2.5*(1.35*(abs(\x-0.4))^0.2-(abs(\x-0.4))^1.6/2-0.0115),0)});
    \draw[blue] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{2.5*(7*(\x^0.57)/(\x^3+6)-\x/60+\x^2/600+0.0079)});
    \draw[green] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/10+\x^2.47/100+0.012)});
    \draw[black] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/9+\x^2.15/39+0.008)});
    }
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw [red] (0.39,0) -- (0.398,0.995);
    \draw [dotted] (1,0) node[below]{$1$} -- (1,4);
    \draw [dotted] (0,2.5) node[left]{$1$} -- (4,2.5);
    \node at (3.6,-.2) {$v_1$};
    \node at (-.4,3.85) {q};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
    \captionof{figure}{caption 2 caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2
    }
    \vfill
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You have to be more specific, like adding other possible figures in your document (make a full MWE) and tell us if there the captions has to be centered too.

Comment: What do you expect when you mess around (please excuse this wording) with the dimensions of the minipages like this. You may want to specify your document class and load all packages, including caption.

Comment: @marmot ah yes, my messing around with the dimensions is probably why I can't have nice things :(

Comment: @koleygr Yes each caption should be centered below the respective graph, and in footnotesize.

Comment: Well, I do not think you need minipages, nor pgfplots, since these plots are tikz only.

Comment: @marmot any other ideas for what would fix my issue?

Comment: Yes, I'd use `local bounding boxes`. Clip does not work like this (i.e. with braces) AFAIK, but you won't need it if you choose the domains appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To first approximation, I'd place the plots in `local bounding box`es and then use `calc` to measure their widths in order to place captions of appropriate widths below them. Of course, you can still tune things, e.g. by excluding the labels of the y axes from the local bounding boxes. With this methods, you have full control. You may even have better control if you used pgfplots, which you loaded, but did not use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=pic A,scale=2.913]
    \draw[red] plot[domain=0:1.785, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{max(0.7*(3*log10(\x+0.23)+4*(abs(\x-0.35))^0.1-2.6+0.67*(abs(\x-0.35))^1.63/12),0)});
    \draw[blue] plot[domain=0:1.785, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{1.24*(\x^2.576)/(0.2+\x^2.24)});
    \draw[green] plot[domain=0:1.785, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{1.24*(\x^(1.15*1.4))/(0.21+\x^1.4)});
    \draw[black] plot[domain=0:1.785, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{1.24*(\x^(1.22*0.5))/(0.21+\x^0.5)});
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1.785,1.785);
    \draw [dotted] (1,0) node[below]{$1$} -- (1,1.785);
    \draw [dotted] (0,1.1161) node[left]{$1$} -- (1.785,1.1161);
    \node at (1.6065,-0.08925) {$v_1$};
    %\node at (-.4,3.85) {\footnotesize $\frac{x_{p}}{x_{s}}$};
    \end{scope}
    \draw let \p1=($(pic A.south east)-(pic A.south west)$) in 
    node[below=3pt of pic A.south,text width=0.9*\x1,align=center]
    {\captionof{figure}{caption 1 caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1caption 1}};
    \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,scale=1.3,local bounding box=pic B]
    \draw[red] plot[domain=0.398:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{max(2.5*(1.35*(abs(\x-0.4))^0.2-(abs(\x-0.4))^1.6/2-0.0115),0)});
    \draw[blue] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{2.5*(7*(\x^0.57)/(\x^3+6)-\x/60+\x^2/600+0.0079)});
    \draw[green] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/10+\x^2.47/100+0.012)});
    \draw[black] plot[domain=0:4, range=0:4, variable=\x,samples=90]  ({\x},{2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/9+\x^2.15/39+0.008)});
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw [red] (0.39,0) -- (0.398,0.995);
    \draw [dotted] (1,0) node[below]{$1$} -- (1,4);
    \draw [dotted] (0,2.5) node[left]{$1$} -- (4,2.5);
    \node at (3.6,-.2) {$v_1$};
    \node at (-.4,3.85) {q};
    \end{scope}
    \draw let \p1=($(pic B.south east)-(pic B.south west)$) in 
    node[below=3pt of pic B.south,text width=0.9*\x1,align=center]
    {\captionof{figure}{caption 2 caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption
    2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption 2caption
    2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps cleaner solution is based on `groupplot`s of pgfplots, where you can (ab)use the title to place the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,every axis title/.append style={at={(0.5,-0.05)},
anchor=north,text width=0.42*\textwidth}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1, horizontal
  sep=0.1*\textwidth},
  xlabel style = {at={(1,0)},anchor=north east},
  xlabel={$v_1$},
  ylabel style = {at={(0,1)},anchor=north east,rotate=-90},
  width=0.45*\textwidth, xtick={1},ytick=\empty]
   \nextgroupplot[domain=0:1.785,
   ymin=0,ymax=2,samples=90,ylabel={$\displaystyle\frac{x_{p}}{x_{s}}$},
    extra y ticks={1.1161},extra y tick labels={1},
    title={\captionof{figure}{This is a very long caption that runs over several
    lines.}}]
    \addplot[red] {max(0.7*(3*log10(\x+0.23)+4*(abs(\x-0.35))^0.1-2.6+0.67*(abs(\x-0.35))^1.63/12),0)};
    \addplot[blue] {1.24*(\x^2.576)/(0.2+\x^2.24)};
    \addplot[green] {1.24*(\x^(1.15*1.4))/(0.21+\x^1.4)};
    \addplot[black] {1.24*(\x^(1.22*0.5))/(0.21+\x^0.5)};
    \draw [dotted] (1,0)  -- (1,4) (-1,1.1161) -- (2,1.1161);
   \nextgroupplot[domain=0.398:4,ymin=0,ymax=4,samples=90,
   extra y ticks={2.5},extra y tick labels={1},ylabel={$q$},
   title={\captionof{figure}{This is another very long caption that runs over several
    lines.}}]
    \addplot[red] {max(2.5*(1.35*(abs(\x-0.4))^0.2-(abs(\x-0.4))^1.6/2-0.0115),0)};
    \addplot[blue] {2.5*(7*(\x^0.57)/(\x^3+6)-\x/60+\x^2/600+0.0079)};
    \addplot[green] {2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/10+\x^2.47/100+0.012)};
    \addplot[black] {2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/9+\x^2.15/39+0.008)};
    \draw [dotted] (1,0)  -- (1,4) (0,2.5) -- (5,2.5);
  \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: possibly a phantom q in the first image is what the OP would like more... (+1)

Comment: @koleygr Thanks! I am aware of this, that's why I wrote ", e.g. by excluding the labels of the y axes from the local bounding boxes". The left plot does have a y label as well, which got clipped away and had somewhat weird coordinates, so I left it out. I also believe that with pgfplots it would be less hassle, no weird scales need to be put in by hand.

Comment: You are right. The other option (opposite)  that comes to my mind is the first q in overlay... Just adding the idea but I am sure you will find a clever way for anything he will add as a demand.

Comment: @koleygr Again I agree but my crystal ball broke so I did not do all these things. I can see *many* ways to improve this, but ultimately these things drive me into a direction where I reinvent the `axis` object from pgfplots, which is not something I am able to do. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- it is not very clear what you mmean with "centering below diagram" :-(
- since you not provide minimal working example i took its preamble from nice [marmot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) answer
- with use of:

  - `minipage`
  - `pgfplots` (which you load but not use in those two diagrams)

  the mwe with your diagrams is:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[skip=1ex,
              font=footnotesize,
              labelfont=bf] {caption}
  \captionsetup{}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \begin{figure}[h]
      \pgfplotsset{width=1.1\linewidth,
                   xlabel={$v_1$},
                   xlabel style = {at={(1,0)},anchor=north east},
                   ylabel style = {at={(0,1)},anchor=north east,rotate=-90},
                   xtick=\empty,
                   ytick=\empty,
                   extra x ticks={1},
                   extra y ticks={1},
                   grid=major,
                   major grid style={densely dotted},
             enlargelimits=false,
                   samples=90,
                   no marks
                   }

      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}\centering%\raggedleft
          \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
      \begin{axis}[
              domain=0:2,
              ylabel={$p$}
                  ]
  \addplot {max(0.7*(3*log10(\x+0.23)+4*(abs(\x-0.35))^0.1-2.6+0.67*(abs(\x-0.35))^1.63/12),0)};
  \addplot {1.24*(\x^2.576)/(0.2+\x^2.24)};
  \addplot {1.24*(\x^(1.15*1.4))/(0.21+\x^1.4)};
  \addplot {1.24*(\x^(1.22*0.5))/(0.21+\x^0.5)};
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}

  \caption{caption 1 caption 1 caption 1 caption 1 caption 1 caption 1caption 1 caption 1 caption 1 caption 1 caption 1}
      \label{fig:fig-1}
      \end{minipage}
  \hfill
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}\centering%\raggedleft
          \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
      \begin{axis}[
              domain=0:4,
              ylabel={$q$},
              ymax=3.3
  %            scaled ticks=false
                  ]
  \addplot +[domain=0.39:4] {max(2.5*(1.35*(abs(\x-0.4))^0.2-(abs(\x-0.4))^1.6/2-0.0115),0)};
  \addplot {2.5*(7*(\x^0.57)/(\x^3+6)-\x/60+\x^2/600+0.0079)};
  \addplot {2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/10+\x^2.47/100+0.012)};
  \addplot {2.5*(7*(\x^0.1)/(\x^(-0.1)+5.5)-\x^1.6/9+\x^2.15/39+0.008)};
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}

  \caption{caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2 caption 2}
      \label{fig:fig-1}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}
  ```

  \end{document}

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: Where do you need `\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}`? Or did you just forget to remove it when you copied things from my answer? Notice also that the right plot doesn't seem quite right, at least in the OP's version there was no horizontal blue stretch.

Comment: @marmot, nowhere, i forgot to remove this from op code. corrected now ... thank you for  warning.

Comment: But the OP doesn't have these in, and never had. However, my answer has precisely this line. You seem to have a really strange editor that adds these things just so. ;-)

Comment: you are right again ...please apologize me, it seems that i use use your preamble! oh, here is midnight and hour for witches ... better that i go to slip.